# localstorage not switching view and producing no errors in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, local-storage

Not sure why this isn't working and could use some assistance.  I'm trying to make it where if you click on "Newsletters", "News" or "Public Announcements", the layout changes to display the correct view and stores in localstorage.

Right now, nothing happens when you click on one of those 3 items mentioned above - It doesn't change the layout view nor does it store data in localstorage...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Changing layout to 'newsletters'
    $('.news_nav-for_nckcn ul li:nth-of-type(1)').on('click', function () {
        changeToNewslettersView();
    });

    // Changing layout to 'news'
    $('.news_nav-for_nckcn ul li:nth-of-type(2)').on('click', function () {
        changeToNewsView();
    });

    $('.news_nav-for_nckcn ul li:nth-of-type(3)').on('click', function () {
        changeToPublicAnnouncementsView();
    });

    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        var view = localStorage.getItem("view");
        if (view && view == "newsletters") {
            changeToNewslettersView();
        } else if (view && view == "news") {
            changeToNewsView();
        } else if (view && view == "publicAnnouncements") {
            changeToPublicAnnouncementsView();
        } else {
            // view isn't set, or is set to something we don't recognize
        }
    } else {
        // user's browser doesn't support localStorage
    }        
});
// Changing layout 'news' & 'publicAnnouncements' to 'newsletters'
function changeToNewslettersView() {
    var news=document.getElementById('hideClass');
    news.style.display="none";

    var publicAnnouncements=document.getElementById('hideClass');
    publicAnnouncements.style.display="none";

    var newsletters=document.getElementById('showClass');
    newsletters.style.display="block";

    storagePut("newsletters");

    $('.news_nav-for_nckcn ul li:nth-of-type(1)').addClass('active');
    $('.news_nav-for_nckcn ul li:nth-of-type(2)').removeClass('active');
    $('.news_nav-for_nckcn ul li:nth-of-type(3)').removeClass('active');
}
// Changing layout 'newsletters' & 'publicAnnouncements' to 'news'
function changeToNewsView() {
    var newsletters=document.getElementById('hideClass');
    newsletters.style.display="none";

    var publicAnnouncements=document.getElementById('hideClass');
    publicAnnouncements.style.display="none";

    var news=document.getElementById('showClass');
    news.style.display="block";

    storagePut("news");

    $('.news_nav-for_nckcn ul li:nth-of-type(2)').addClass('active');
    $('.news_nav-for_nckcn ul li:nth-of-type(1)').removeClass('active');
    $('.news_nav-for_nckcn ul li:nth-of-type(3)').removeClass('active');
}
// Changing layout 'newsletters' & 'news' to 'publicAnnouncements'
function changeToPublicAnnouncementsView() {
    var newsletters=document.getElementById('hideClass');
    newsletters.style.display="none";

    var news=document.getElementById('hideClass');
    news.style.display="none";

    var publicAnnouncements=document.getElementById('showClass');
    publicAnnouncements.style.display="block";

    storagePut("publicAnnouncements");

    $('.news_nav-for_nckcn ul li:nth-of-type(3)').addClass('active');
    $('.news_nav-for_nckcn ul li:nth-of-type(1)').removeClass('active');
    $('.news_nav-for_nckcn ul li:nth-of-type(2)').removeClass('active');
}
function storagePut(view) {
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        localStorage.setItem("view", view);
    } else {
        // user's browser doesn't support localStorage
    }        
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/k6c1y320/)

Comment: Console error: "TypeError: news is null". There's no element with ID "hideClass".

Comment: Html elements cannot have multiple ids. You have to use some "hidden" class on your hidden contents insteads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that you are trying to get the element with the id "hideClass"

From your demo, we can see :

```
    <div id="2017-newsletters hideClass" class="nckcn_news_container-wrapper_newsletters">
```

As you can see [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.10), you can only have one id per element :

> In XML, fragment identifiers are of type ID, and there can only be a single attribute of type ID per element. Therefore, in XHTML 1.0 the id attribute is defined to be of type ID. In order to ensure that XHTML 1.0 documents are well-structured XML documents, XHTML 1.0 documents MUST use the id attribute when defining fragment identifiers on the elements listed above. See the HTML Compatibility Guidelines for information on ensuring such anchors are backward compatible when serving XHTML documents as media type text/html.

The usual way of manipulating html tabs is by adding class to the hidden elements (but you can also add a class on the visible element if it suits you better), and then get your elements by class not by id

Comment: Thx Logar!  That seemed to do the trick!  I can't believe I missed that...

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `news` and corresponding variables were evaluating to `null`, Hence `news.style` gave null error and terminated script execution. I've tried to fix the demo. It's now changing tabs as well as setting the localStorage.

[See JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/k6c1y320/1/)